# How to group data in a DataFrame and also show the number of row in that group?

Tags: python, dataframe

first of all, I have no background in computer language and I am learning Python.

I'm trying to group some data in a data frame.

[dataframe "cafe_df_merged"]
[image]

Actually, I want to create a new data frame shows the 'city_number', 'city' (which is a name), and also the number of cafes in the same city. So, it should have 3 columns; 'city_number', 'city' and 'number_of_cafe'

However, I have tried to use the group by but the result did not come out as I expected.

```
city_directory = cafe_df_merged[['city_number', 'city']]
city_directory = city_directory.groupby('city').count()
city_directory
```

[the result]

[image]
How should I do this? Please help, thanks.

Comment: Hi @gushady. Please don't post images, instead paste it as code. It's always great to have a sample input with expected output for the better understanding of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely other ways of doing this as well, but something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a reproducible example
places = [[['starbucks', 'new_york', '1234']]*5, [['bean_dream', 'boston', '3456']]*4, \
             [['coffee_today', 'jersey', '7643']]*3, [['coffee_today', 'DC', '8902']]*3, \
             [['starbucks', 'nowwhere', '2674']]*2]
places = [p for sub in places for p in sub]

# a dataframe containing all information
city_directory = pd.DataFrame(places, columns=['shop','city', 'id'])

# make a new dataframe with just cities and ids
# drop duplicate rows
city_info = city_directory.loc[:, ['city','id']].drop_duplicates()

# get the cafe counts (number of cafes)
cafe_count = city_directory.groupby('city').count().iloc[:,0]

# add the cafe counts to the dataframe
city_info['cafe_count'] = cafe_count[city_info['city']].to_numpy()

# reset the index
city_info = city_info.reset_index(drop=True)
```

`city_info` now yields the following:

```
    city        id     cafe_count
0   new_york    1234    5
1   boston      3456    4
2   jersey      7643    3
3   DC          8902    3
4   nowwhere    2674    2
```

And part of the example dataframe, `city_directory.tail()`, looks like this:

```
    shop            city        id
12  coffee_today    DC          8902
13  coffee_today    DC          8902
14  coffee_today    DC          8902
15  starbucks       nowwhere    2674
16  starbucks       nowwhere    2674
```

---

*Opinion*: As a side note, it might be easier to get comfortable with regular Python first before diving deep into the world of pandas and numpy. Otherwise, it might be a bit overwhelming.